# $\Pr(X>aY+b,Y>c) = 1 - \Pr(X\le aY+b) - \Pr(Y\le c) + \Pr((X<aY+b) \cap (Y<c))$

Tags: probability

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Pr}{Pr}$If $X$ and $Y$ are independent RV, is

$\Pr(X>aY+b,Y>c) = 1 - \Pr(X\le aY+b) - \Pr(Y\le c) + \Pr((X<aY+b)\cap(Y<c))$

correct?

$a,b,c $ are constants

Edit: corrected the equation

Comment: No, it is not correct. How did you get it?

Comment: Sorry I missed writing the 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Pr}{Pr}$I think it would be $\Pr(X>aY+b,Y>c) = \Pr(X>aY+b) + \Pr(Y>c) - \Pr((X>aY+b)\cap(Y>c))$

Comment: I have edited the question as I had missed something, could you recheck it?

Comment: Well, I'm just going by the inclusion-exclusion principle to get the equation I posted; going your way, it would be a bit more complex, like, it wold be $1 - \Pr(Y>c)$ instead of just $-\Pr(Y>c)$